# Manipulação de imagem do lado cliente

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, canvas, front-end

Surgiu um desafio, preciso saber como/quais ferramentas pode me auxiliar a criar uma area que posso manipular imagem do lado do cliente. Preciso desenvolver um site que cria camisas personalizadas, algo como [vitrinepix](http://www.vitrinepix.com.br/crie2), não sou tão bom dev front-end mas ja me vieram em mente algumas possibilidades, canvas e javascript? será que existe alguma biblioteca que me auxilie para isso?

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas opções de bibliotecas bem interessantes, tais como:

- http://fabricjs.com/

  - Exemplo: http://fabricjs.com/clipping/
- http://paperjs.org/

  - Exemplo: http://paperjs.org/examples/path-simplification/
- http://html-canvas-lib.sourceforge.net/

  - Exemplo: http://html-canvas-lib.sourceforge.net/canvas/

São os melhores na minha opinião.